# Changes showing in FF4.0 but no other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I'm having a VERY weird problem,
I have added a tabbed content style switcher on the right hand sidebar of my site but it's only showing up in FF4.0, all other browsers are showing the old version, I have tried cache clearing and everything but to no avail,

Screenshots:
FF4.0b10:

[image: Firefox 4.0 beta 10]

Any other browser:

[image]

Anyone else ever experienced this?

Link: http://mutant-tractor.com

Comment: Mine looks like the second block on FF4.0b10

Comment: Perhaps it's more of a problem with how FF4 is rendering your code, and not a matter of browsers showing an old version?  I see your "old" version.  Try changing something simple, like adding the word test to your output.  If you see it, you're seeing the "current" version.

Comment: Thanks Matt + Surreal, It seems that my computer is the only one showing the updated version and its only in FF4b10 I see it... weird, Its definitely not being hosted locally and there isn't any `@override`'s in the code either, I have updated with test1,2,3,4 and 5, it is showing up the changes in my FF4b10 but not in anything else, what makes this even more strange is that if I play songs BOTH versions update with the new songs but not the layout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing this [on SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/310681#310681), it appears that it's a problem with the host.  It seems like a DNS propagation issue or an issue with their DNS servers.  So it should be a temporal issue that should resolve itself after a while.

As far as how to fix it, as said in chat, the best way seems to be to find a new/better host...